# Testwise chose a specific story or test case to run

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, testwise

Does testwise allow to run specific test case?

Let's say I have a CSV that has story or test case called test hyperlink and then read in the csv and run only that test case.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @justinko u know about this justin? thanks

Comment: I have not used Testwise beyond a short evaluation. From what I recall, Testwise has a UI to select/run single (and multiple) test cases. I do not recall any csv reading capabilities, though I would not have been looking for it.